# Prove that an elementary function is non-decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For $p > 0$, define :

$f(p) := \int_0^1{p (1-x)^{p^2 + 2p}e^{\frac{(1+p)^2}{2} x(x+2)}}dx$

The question is : how to prove that $f$ is a non-decreasing function of p?

It seems to be the case numerically.

Note that one can show that $p \mapsto f(p)/p$ is a non-increasing function because $f(p)/p = \int_0^1{\frac{1}{1-x}e^{(1+p)^2[\ln{(1-x)} + \frac{x(x+2)}{2}]}dx}$ and $\ln{(1-x)} + \frac{x(x+2)}{2}$ is always negative. So the difficulty here is to understand why does the factor $p$ help!

Thanks a lot for any clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't difficult, just somewhat tricky.

Let $w(x)=\log(1-x)+x+\frac{x^2}2=-\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4-\dots$. We need to show that the product of $f(p)=\int_0^1\frac 1{1-x}e^{(1+p)^2w(x)}\,dx$ and $p$ is increasing. Note that $-w'(x)=\frac 1{1-x}-1-x$, so $f(p)=\frac 1{(1+p)^2}+\int_0^1(1+x)e^{(1+p)^2w(x)}\,dx=\frac{1}{(1+p)^2}+g(p)$.

***Claim 1:*** The function $u(p)=(p+1)g(p)$ is increasing.

Indeed, take any $q>p$ and define $a=\frac{1+p}{1+q}$. Notice now that $w$ is decreasing and $(1+q)^2 w(a^{2/3}x)\ge (1+p)^2 w(x)$, so it suffices to show that for every $y\in(0,1)$, we have
$$
\int_0^{a^{2/3}y}(1+x)\,dx=a^{2/3}y+a^{4/3}\frac{y^2}2\ge a\int_0^y(1+x)\,dx=ay+a\frac{y^2}2
$$ 
But since $\frac{y^2}2<y$, the two terms on the left have the same product as the two terms on the right, but are farther apart, so this is obvious.

***Claim 2:*** $u(p)\ge 1$.

Indeed, we have
$$
u(p)\ge u(0)=g(0)=\int_0^1(1-x^2)e^{x+\frac{x^2}2}\,dx\ge\int_0^1(1-x^2)(1+x+x^2)\,dx
\\
=1-\frac 13+\frac 12-\frac 14+\frac 13-\frac 15=1+\frac 14-\frac 15>1\,.
$$

Now it is time to differentiate $pf(p)=\frac{p}{(1+p)^2}+u(p)\frac{p}{1+p}$. We get 
$$
\frac 1{(1+p)^2}-\frac{2p}{(1+p)^3}+\frac{u(p)}{(1+p)^2}+u'(p)\frac{p}{1+p}> \frac{1+u(p)-2}{(1+p)^2}+u'(p)\frac{p}{1+p}\ge 0\,.
$$

The end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis. I have understand how you have reduced my initial problem to Claim 1. This is brillant because your $u$ seems nicer than my $f$. May you please detail a little bit the proof of Claim 1 ? I have troubles to understand why does the fact that for every $y \in (0,1)$, $\int_0^{a^{2/3}y}(1+x)\,dx \geq a\int_0^y(1+x)\,dx$ implies the fact that $u(p) < u(q)$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Adri This is just the "general mumbo-jumbo": If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two positive decreasing functions on $[0,1]$ such:that $f(bx)\ge g(x)$ for every $x$ with some $b<1$, and $\{g>t\}=[0,y_t)$ then for any measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$, we have $\int_0^1 f\,d\mu=\int_{0}^\infty \mu(\{f>t\})\,dt\ge \int_0^\infty\mu([0,by_t))\,dt\ge a\int_0^\infty\mu([0,y_t))\,dt=a\int_0^1g\,d\mu$, provided that $\mu([0,by))\ge a\mu([0,y))$ for all $y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Got it, it is very ingenious :) Thanks, again! But, following your argument, why did you not write directly : $\int_0^1{f d\mu} = \int_0^{\infty}{\mu \{f>t \}dt} \geq \int_0^{\infty}{\mu\{g>t\}dt} =\int_0^1{g d \mu} > a \int_0^1{gd \mu}$ for any $a<1$? It seems that it would gives the result directly without having to check that $\int_0^{a^{2/3}y}(1+x)\,dx \ge a\int_0^y(1+x)\,dx$ , isn't?

Comment: @Adry Because I only have $f(bx)\ge g(x)$, not $f(x)>g(x)$, so there is no chance to get an inequality as strong as $\mu(\{f>t\})\ge \mu(\{g>t\})$

Comment: Oh, yes of course - I misunderstood your first comment! Great, I am now happy :)